# Front-End Plug-In Page

Tags: url-rewriting, wordpress

Ok, so I've looked at many posts on here about similar topics, but every single one of them is a rewrite rule for an actual php file in the url such as `cart.php` rather than the pretty permalink `/cart/`.

Basically, all I'm trying to do here is have WordPress include a template whenever a specific url is visited. In this case, example.com/cart/. Since this code is for a plug-in, it's a url that does not exist, and I cannot create a page for it. I'm trying to use a rewrite rule, along with query vars, to display the correct template when the user visits /cart/. I think I'm pretty close, but I've tried it several different ways, and I know I'm probably missing something obvious. I keep getting a 404 error, and I'm pretty sure it's my rewrite rule that is the problem. Can you guys give me a hand with this one?

Code:

```
/* Rewrite Rules */
add_action('init', 'llc_product_rewrite_rule');
function llc_product_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cart/', 'index.php?llc_page=cart', 'top' );
}

/* Query Vars */
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'llc_product_register_query_var' );
function llc_product_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'llc_page';
    return $vars;
}

/* Parse Request */
add_action('parse_request', 'llc_cart_template');
function llc_cart_template() {
    if (get_query_var('llc_page') && (get_query_var('llc_page') == "cart")) {   
    include plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'inc/cart.php';
    exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your well thought out responses you guys, but unfortunately I don't have all day and had to go through trial and error hell to figure this one out.

So firstly, if you want to simply have `example.com/cart/` load a specific page template, when the page does not exist (for example if you need your wordpress plug-in to generate the page), this is how you'll need to set up your code. To clarify what's different from the code in my question, it's the rewrite rule, and the way I included the template. I used `template_include` rather than `parse_request`.

```
/* Rewrite Rules */
add_action('init', 'llc_product_rewrite_rule');
function llc_product_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cart/?$', 'index.php?llc_page=cart', 'top' );
}

/* Query Vars */
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'llc_product_register_query_var' );
function llc_product_register_query_var( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'llc_page';
    return $vars;
}

/* Template Include */
add_filter('template_include', 'llc_cart_template_include', 1, 1);
function llc_cart_template_include($template)
{
    global $wp_query;
    $llc_page_value = $wp_query->query_vars['llc_page'];

    if ($llc_page_value && $llc_page_value == "cart") {
        return plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'inc/cart.php';
    }

    return $template;
}
```